# aerospike service start error /usr/bin/asd: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/bin/asd)

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, glibc, aerospike

I am getting error when i am executing following command in ec2 machine 
        sudo /etc/init.d/aerospike start

I need aerospike engine in my ec2 machine for test purpose. 
I used 
        wget -O aerospike.tgz 'http://aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu12 to get the file and installed it as the doc says.

Comment: which ubuntu version are you using?(ubuntu12 or ubuntu14) You could also try the marketplace AMI of Aerospike.

Comment: Can you let me know which AMI id did you use to setup your instance? I tried both ubuntu 12 and 14; works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I just happened to see this question.  Have you resolved it?  Did you get the proper version of GLibC installed?

If not, it looks like you are using the 3.5.3 community version, correct?

I tested in AWS on Ubuntu 14.4 M3 large, and it installed and started fine:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-5:~$ wget -O aerospike.tgz 'http://aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu12
> ^C
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-5:~$ wget -O aerospike.tgz 'http://aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu12'
--2015-03-09 21:29:58--  http://aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu12
Resolving aerospike.com (aerospike.com)... 184.168.221.29
Connecting to aerospike.com (aerospike.com)|184.168.221.29|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu12 [following]
--2015-03-09 21:29:59--  http://aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu12
Connecting to aerospike.com (aerospike.com)|184.168.221.29|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu12 [following]
--2015-03-09 21:29:59--  http://aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu12
Connecting to aerospike.com (aerospike.com)|184.168.221.29|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu12[following]
--2015-03-09 21:29:59--  http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu12
Resolving www.aerospike.com (www.aerospike.com)... 54.215.231.2, 54.183.249.41
Connecting to www.aerospike.com (www.aerospike.com)|54.215.231.2|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.aerospike.com/cgi/latest.php?/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu12 [following]
--2015-03-09 21:29:59--  http://www.aerospike.com/cgi/latest.php?/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu12
Reusing existing connection to www.aerospike.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /download/server/3.5.3/artifact/ubuntu12 [following]
--2015-03-09 21:29:59--  http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/3.5.3/artifact/ubuntu12
Reusing existing connection to www.aerospike.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.aerospike.com/cgi/artifact.php?/download/server/3.5.3/artifact/ubuntu12 [following]
--2015-03-09 21:29:59--  http://www.aerospike.com/cgi/artifact.php?/download/server/3.5.3/artifact/ubuntu12
Reusing existing connection to www.aerospike.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.aerospike.com/artifacts/aerospike-server-community/3.5.3/aerospike-server-community-3.5.3... [following]
--2015-03-09 21:29:59--  http://www.aerospike.com/artifacts/aerospike-server-community/3.5.3/aerospike-server-community-3.5.3...
Reusing existing connection to www.aerospike.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 10518026 (10M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘aerospike.tgz’

100%[=========================================================================================================================================================================================>] 10,518,026  17.6MB/s  in 0.6s  

2015-03-09 21:30:00 (17.6 MB/s) - ‘aerospike.tgz’ saved [10518026/10518026]

ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-5:~$ ls -ltrh
total 11M
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 11M Mar  3 23:57 aerospike.tgz
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-5:~$ tar xvf aerospike.tgz 
aerospike-server-community-3.5.3-ubuntu12.04/
aerospike-server-community-3.5.3-ubuntu12.04/asinstall
aerospike-server-community-3.5.3-ubuntu12.04/aerospike-server-community-3.5.3.ubuntu12.04.x86_64.deb
aerospike-server-community-3.5.3-ubuntu12.04/aerospike-tools-3.5.2.ubuntu12.04.x86_64.deb
aerospike-server-community-3.5.3-ubuntu12.04/LICENSE
aerospike-server-community-3.5.3-ubuntu12.04/SHA256SUMS
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-5:~$ cd aerospike-server-community-3.5.3-ubuntu12.04/
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-5:~/aerospike-server-community-3.5.3-ubuntu12.04$ ls -ltrh
total 11M
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 8.1K Dec  5 20:24 LICENSE
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1.1K Dec  5 20:24 asinstall
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3.7M Feb 23 23:38 aerospike-tools-3.5.2.ubuntu12.04.x86_64.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  563 Feb 23 23:43 SHA256SUMS
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 6.6M Feb 23 23:43 aerospike-server-community-3.5.3.ubuntu12.04.x86_64.deb
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-5:~/aerospike-server-community-3.5.3-ubuntu12.04$ sudo ./asinstall 
Installing tools
dpkg -i aerospike-tools-3.5.2.ubuntu12.04.x86_64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package aerospike-tools.
(Reading database ... 51108 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack aerospike-tools-3.5.2.ubuntu12.04.x86_64.deb ...
Unpacking aerospike-tools (3.5.2) ...
Setting up aerospike-tools (3.5.2) ...
Installing /opt/aerospike
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aerospike.pth
Adding python path /opt/aerospike/lib/python
Installing server
dpkg -i aerospike-server-community-3.5.3.ubuntu12.04.x86_64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package aerospike-server-community.
(Reading database ... 51160 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack aerospike-server-community-3.5.3.ubuntu12.04.x86_64.deb ...
Unpacking aerospike-server-community (3.5.3-1) ...
Setting up aerospike-server-community (3.5.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-5:~/aerospike-server-community-3.5.3-ubuntu12.04$ sudo /etc/init.d/aerospike start
* Start aerospike:  asd                                                                                                                                                                                                          kernel.shmall too low, setting to 4G pages = 16TB
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
kernel.shmmax too low, setting to 1GB
kernel.shmmax = 1073741824
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            [ OK ]
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-5:~/aerospike-server-community-3.5.3-ubuntu12.04$ sudo /etc/init.d/aerospike status
* asd is running
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-5:~/aerospike-server-community-3.5.3-ubuntu12.04$
```

Let us know if the issue persists.

Hope this helps,

-DM

Answer (score 2):

You may be also to install latest glibc if its an older version.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

Comment: Thanks mate :) Actually i was running it on 11.10 and then i realized . After this i updated the system and it worked.